# One product has unlimited categories and the other way

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables with relationship N:N.
I need to select one item with more than one categories and one category with more than one item.
First table is products.
Second table between them is products_category.
Third table is category.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

---

I've tried this

```
select products.nazev, category.nazev AS 'name_category' 
from products 
join products_category on products.id = products_category.id 
join category on products_category.id = category.id
```

But I had no luck.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and what you have tried so far please

Comment: I've tried this

select products.nazev, category.nazev AS 'name_category' from 
products join products_category on products.id = products_category.id 
join category on products_category.id = category.id 

But I had no luck.

Comment: Please take a moment to setup a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some expected data because it will encourage people to post something relevant rather than waste time with comments such as the one I am writing. There is also no visible reason for the PHP tag other than I assume you are using PHP on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your second table (products_category) needs to have foreign keys to link it with products and category.  Then the SQL query needs to join properly with those foreign keys:

```
select products.nazev, category.nazev AS 'name_category' 
from products 
join products_category on products.id = products_category.product_id 
join category on products_category.category_id = category.id
```